# Hash Table Column Values as Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I have followed [this tutorial](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-persist-hashes-in-rails-applications-with-postgresql/) to have a hash column on my model which works great.

When I work out codes in the `rails console`, it becomes different within my controller code. In the console:

```
Foo.update_attributes(bar: {"a" => 1, "b" => 2})
```

My values are shown as an integer, in the console. In my controller, if I'm doing calculations, I have to add `.to_i` or `.to_f` and it becomes messy. My values will forever be a number. Can I simple add an int or float for the column?

```
add_column :foos, :bar, :hstore, :integer, default: {}, null: false
```

The above does not work.

Comment: What you mean by "They are shown as an integer". You mean if you call class on the value, that is showing you `Fixnum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a hook on your model:

```
before_save -> r { r.bar.each{|k, v| r.bar[k] = v.to_i} }
```